# Looking for a JQuery solution to checkbox design

Tags: jquery, css, checkbox

I'm trying to create a checkbox group where the option names can be clicked to toggle checked and unchecked states. Also I don't want to show the boxes and ticks at all. Just the option name which changes color when it is clicked to show "checked" and "unchecked" states. Does anyone know of a simple way to do this with JQuery?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: its better show what you try?

Comment: Check out [**this plugin**](https://github.com/elclanrs/jq-idealforms)

Comment: Thanks! I'll put up my code next time.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hey now check for this url

http://line25.com/articles/jquery-plugins-for-styling-checkbox-radio-buttons